# Parse complex numbers with exponential notation Java

Tags: java

Trying to read some complex numbers in from a csv file. I have a String and am trying

```java
ComplexFormat cf = new ComplexFormat();
cf.parse(entry)
```

This code results in the following error

```
org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathParseException: illegal state: string "-7.5212e-06+3.4298e-06i" unparseable (from position 7) as an object of type org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex
```

I am assuming I need to create a new complex format with a NumberFormat that allows for exponential notation since

```java
cf.getRealFormat().useExponentialNotation = false
```

However I am unsure how to create such a NumberFormat. I am otherwise thinking of using Double.parseDouble but that would require me to think of the correct regular expression.

Comment: That's too little code, try to provide more please. How's `ComplexFormat` defined, where does `entry` comes from and it's expected format. Show more.

Comment: @user3676491 edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data seems to contain the scientific notation with a small e. It is annoying that the library does not intercept but a simple replace will help in your case.

```
String entry = "-7.5212e-06+3.4298e-06i";
ComplexFormat cf = new ComplexFormat();
Complex c = cf.parse(entry.replace('e', 'E'));
System.out.println(c);
//(-0.075212, 0.034298)
```

But note if you use the default constructor (as above) your numbers will be parsed correctly but the scientific notation will not be maintained anymore. if you want to keep the notation, use DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.####E0", symbols);
ComplexFormat cfWithE = new ComplexFormat(formatter);
Complex c2 = cfWithE.parse(entry.replace('e', 'E'));
System.out.println(c2);
//(-7.5212E-6, 3.4298E-6)
```